# SQL: set value with condition

Tags: sql

I have some Problem, there are two Tables, they communicate with the value ID.
Now I will set the value from Column **a** in Table **A** with the value 'Nein', but only if the value of the column **b** in Table **B** is '0' and 
if a.id = b.id.

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a Join in the Update Statement like:

```
UPDATE a set ColumnA='Nein' from TableA a inner join TableB b on a.id=b.id WHERE b.ColumnB='0'
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below query . Since there here i am not sure that id is primary column in table , i have used "in" clause .

```
update A 
set A.a ='Nein' 
where A.id in ( select A.id from A ,B
where A.id = B.id and B.b='0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
update A a set a.a='Nein' 
where a.id in (select b.id from B b where B.b='0' and a.id=b.id);
```